# Calculating distance with pincode (Google map Distance Matrix API)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing web application on MVC, I have a requirement to automatically find the distance between two locations using the pin code. So, I started using the google map distance matrix API as below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" + Convert.ToString(origin) + "&destinations=" + Convert.ToString(destination) + "&key='MY key'
```

API is working fine for pin codes of India, but I have to deploy the application on Cambodia and for Cambodia pin code the API is not working.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I think that pin code are only used in india so can't use it in other country. you don't have the lat/lng of the points ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @Aznhar: the application we have lot of place in master and client will add more. So we can't ask them to enter lat/lng.. That's why we preferred pincode.

Comment: @geocodezip: please find below the two example API with values. The API which works for me is "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=613004&destinations=560001&key='MY key'". I am trying the same with the only change from Indian pin code to Cambodia Pincode:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=12413&destinations=12211&key='MY key'". but this api is not returning values for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a look at your request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=12413&destinations=12211&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Please note that `12413` and `12211` in origins and destinations parameters are very ambiguous values. You have to provide more precise addresses in order to get results. The Distance Matrix API will geocode the `12413` and `12211` internally.

For example, the `12413` will be geocoded to 'Cairo, NY 12413, USA' a postal code in the USA. You can see this in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D12413

The `12211` will be geocoded to 'Albany, NY 12211, USA':

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D12211

In both cases it's not a pin code in Cambodia as you expect.

Even more, when I try to find a postal code `12413` or `12211` in Cambodia using a component filtering I get ZERO_RESULTS:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#in_postal_code%3D12413%26in_country%3DKH%26options%3Dtrue

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#in_postal_code%3D12211%26in_country%3DKH%26options%3Dtrue

Attempts to get postal code from reverse geocoding of coordinate in Cambodia also lead to ZERO_RESULTS:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=11.55486%2C104.905679&result_type=postal_code&key=MY_API_KEY`

Although the locality for the same coordinate can be found:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=11.55486%2C104.905679&result_type=locality&key=MY_API_KEY`

It's 'Phnom Penh' with place ID `ChIJ42tqxz1RCTERuyW1WugOAZw`.

Taking into account all these facts it looks like Google doesn't have pin code information for Cambodia in their database.

I can suggest using a place autocomplete in your application. This way the user can select a suggested address and you can use a place ID selected by user to execute distance matrix requests. Have also a look at geocoding best practices in official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

I hope this helps!